# Melee Bard Build

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, bard

I'm starting my first pathfinder campaign and I love the bard as a class. I want to make a melee centric bard, while sticking to the basic bard as much as possible with a 25 point buy. The idea I have is a character akin to Loki, when combat fails he always falls back on his smart mouth to manipulate the situation. I believe the Arcane Duelist would be best for this, but I don't know where to start.

My question is what feats and abilities would best be taken to enable this play-style?

Comment: Why without archetypes? There are excellent archetypes for combat-oriented bards.

Comment: I'm not sure why I like the classic bard, but if you have any suggestions I'm game.  I just don't like the idea of heavy armor and I can't see any way to make a melee bard without it.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have to agree with Shadow on that. Archetypes exist to help focus a class into a more specialized flavor or role, and can greatly help a character excel at a specialization.

Comment: There are bard archeytypes that allow for melee combat but not heavy armor, such as [Dervish Dancer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/dervish-dancer),  [Daredevil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/dervish-dancer), and [Arcane Duelist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/dervish-dancer) etc. Are light armor melee archetypes an option?

Comment: For that matter, Heavy Armor is almost not necessary in Pathfinder; Dex builds tend to have very similar (non-flat-footed) AC due Mithral Chain Shirt (4 AC) + up to 6 AC from DEX; Mithral Full Plate only allows for up to 9+3, a 2 point difference. Sure, you could get the Mithral Full Plate some time before +6 DEX, but not by a large margin.

Comment: One more thing, have you looked at the [Skald](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/) hybrid class?

Comment: No I haven't looked into the skald, would you recommend it? I want to play an aasimar because the Cha bonus would only help a bard or skald right?

Comment: Well I tried to edit the quesiton to reflect the authors comment "Ok, I'm convinced, what would be a good build for an arcane duelist? The thing I have the hardest time with are the feats." – Joseph Young, but was shot down. Please update your question to reflect this comment, as well as narrow the scope of the question so it can be taken off hold.

Comment: Ok updated the question.  I like the idea of a story teller....being able to use basic performances anywhere without needing an instrument is a huge plus, is there any way this can be done with the arcane duelist Archetype? I know that you loose basic knowledge and some performance potions.

Comment: You dont actually lose performance points. Just the knowledge skills. Bladethirst however is a performance and thus will take up your maintained performance. It will not however stop you from using certain bardic masterpieces (as long as they dont require to be maintained!) that help you fit this flavor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To enable an arcane duelist to maintain combat effectiveness in the front lines, some of your best options are:**

- [Allegro](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/allegro/) (2nd level spell) Gain haste while performing.
- [Bladed Dash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bladed-dash) (2nd level spell) Can be used to get in/out or around the battlefield while doing damage.
- [Improved Feint](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-feint-combat-final/) (Feat) Leverages bardic charisma to make foes easier to hit

So you wanna be an Arcane Duelist huh?

Well first things first, they inherently get Arcane strike, which is a nice little bonus damage that gets multiplied on crit. Not a bad free feat. However at level 5 and 6 they get the ability to forge a bond with a weapon, allowing them to bestow magic properties upon it as if they were a wizard. This also gives them an extra spell per day (As per [wizards bonded weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-)), and while performing, they can further enhance the magical properties on their weapon.

> For an item with only an enhancement bonus and no other abilities, the caster level is three times the enhancement bonus.

This means that by level 6 you will potentially have a +3 weapon. (+2 from crafted wizard bond, +1 from performance) So a +2 Flaming weapon at level 6? Not too shabby.

Now add in the spell allegro and you are effectively hasted while keeping your weapon nice and powerful. This will give you as many attacks per turn as a fighter of the same level, at least.

**Now for tactics!**

So, I personally recommend a reach weapon for this. While normally bards wouldnt have a point distribution to be strong, dextrious, charismatic, and full of constitution, with 25, you may be able to come close and can get away without.

With a reach weapon, [Bladed Dash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bladed-dash) is an amazing spell. By utilizing this, feints, and some trips, you can effectively make your opponent useless while beating their face in. In order to approach you they would need to take an attack of opportunity.  If you decide to take [Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat-final/) feats, You can then promptly make them fall on their face giving you an AOO, both then, and when they try to stand up. Bladed Dash, will then let you re-position yourself to do this again, without provoking AOOs yourself. Since Bladed Dash is a standard action, you can also feint an opponent as a move action with improved feint before casting to make them easier to hit. A prone, feinted enemy has no dex bonus, and -4ac from prone, making them ripe easy targets and makes up for your lack of full bab. This can be done as early as level 8, and if trip is successful, will deny your opponent full round actions that cant be done prone, and give nearby allies extra AOOs.

Eventually with [metamagic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic-final/), Bladed Dash can be performed as a swift action. Letting you Take a hasted full round attack on a tripped opponent, before bladed dashing away taking another free hit, and forcing them to have to run back through your threatened area.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced, what would be a good build for an arcane duelist? The thing I have the hardest time with are the feats.

Comment: I know that the bard is a support class, I just want to be able to support from the front lines.

Comment: Taking some of the feats and spells I listed could help you support from the front lines, but you would still be supporting. I have a Arcane Healer Bard, who poses as a cleric, and uses a masterpiece to emulate the cleric spell shield of faith for extra AC for teammates, but can use it on themself for extra durability in the frontlines. I will update my answer to reflect how the arcane duelist can utilize its features in achieving your goal..

Comment: Str15 dex15 con13 int13 wis10 cha14

Comment: Those are the stats I've come up with, race aasimar for the Cha and Wis bump, they also have some nice resistances.

Comment: @JosephYoung if your goal is to be a melee bard then you're going to find yourself kind of floundering with those stats. If your plan is to be an Aasimar, I recommend you use the Angel-Blooded alternate heritage (which gives you +STR/+CHA), and then use ability scores closer to 18/14/14/12/8/16 (25 point buy, including racial mod). This will, in general, make you much more effective in your desired role.

Comment: @JosephYoung Additionally, I'm going to toss out a recommendation for the [Flagbearer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/flagbearer-local) feat, with a [Banner of the Ancient Kings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/banner-of-the-ancient-kings/) when you can afford it. This bumps up the bonus from Flagbearer AND your from Inspire Courage, and between them they're going to give you some massive to hit and damage bonuses, not to mention sharing that glory with the party.

Comment: Im not sure the arcane duelist can use inspire courage, and their performance that makes their weapon more magical at the same time. So Inspire courage may not get much use for an arcane duelist. and a +5 (or +4 for you and one other) worth of enchantments on your weapon is a big bonus as well.

Comment: @Erudaki They can never use two performances at once. **"Each round, the bard can produce any one of the types of bardic performance that he has mastered, as indicated by his level."** and **"Changing a bardic performance from one effect to another requires the bard to stop the previous performance and start a new one as a standard action."**

Comment: @Erudaki Additionally, outside of very non-combat oriented parties, Inspire Courage is going to be the better choice. It's really a bard's bread and butter.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. But as the op stated he wants his bard heavily involved in fighting. While under normal circumstances I would agree with you, yes, inspire courage provides better bonuses to a party of decent size, bladethirst would provide him personally with more damage output and combat options, as he can basically drop any +5 worth of weapon enchantments he wants depending on the situation. Giving him several extra dice of damage, or various other abilities. Also if the party is rather small, being able to give 2 of 3 people +4 worth of enchantments is nothing to scoff at ether.